# Find out if a type is being referenced and hence may be potentially loaded at some point in time

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I should know this but can't seem to remember.

How do I find out if a type is being used in an assembly (and not just that it exists in the assembly, which is the easy part).

```
class Dog { }

class Cat { }

class Rat { }

public object GetAnimal()
{
  if (today.Is(DayOfWeek.Monday))
  {
    return new Dog();
  }
  else
  {
    return new Cat();
  }
}
```

I want both Cat and Dog to show up as they can potentially be loaded at some time, but since Rat isn't being used, I don't want it to show up in my results.

Comment: To make it clear: You want *list of types currently loaded in the app domain* or *list of types may be loaded in the app domain*? If GetAnimal is not called yet, `Dog` and `Cat` will not have been loaded in that case you need it or not?

Comment: May be you want alter access level of classes based on condition. Am I right?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Actually, I want both. Hence, the two scenarios. But let's simplify it a bit for now. Let's just say that I want the types that *may be loaded* but are not necessarily currently loaded.

Comment: The types that *may* be loaded is simply the union of all types of all assemblies in the app domain. Can I ask what the intended purpose for this is?

Comment: If your question is *may be loaded* then **nobody** can answer it as you can call any method anytime with reflection. If your question is currently loaded types there is no managed way (I don't know other way either) but debuggers does this for instance [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can say whether type is jitted(can assume it is loaded) or not. So there is a way but I don't know how.

Comment: Okay, let me simplify the question. This is really mixing up two questions. I am updating it to make our discussion more focussed.

Comment: ++ for SOS. Someone actually asked me this question and I pondered a bit and then thought -- damn! I should know it, but can't quite remember. My first bet was to call something on GC but then I saw and realized that that wasn't going to be very specific type information I could get from the GC. Then, SOS occurred to me.

Comment: Please explain why you want to know this, as it helps more experienced users see the actual problem you're trying to solve. You will most likely need static analysis, as you'll have to walk over all code to see in this case whether `GetAnimal()` is being called by any code, whether the code calling `GetAnimal()` is being called, and so on.

Comment: I wonder how reflector would do something like this. Oh, wait. I can look up ILSpy source for this.

Comment: If you mean ReSharper instead of reflector, the answer definitely is ["static analysis"](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_analysis.html).

Comment: @CodeCaster Someone just asked me this question, an ex-colleague. He asked if Roslyn was the way to go. I thought that would be an overkill for a job as simple as this. Turns out not. Alright then, I could do static analysis with several tools - CCI Metadata, Roslyn, NRefactory, etc. etc. et

Comment: Sure, Resharper, too. But Reflector as well. If you right-click a type or a method or anything and say "Analyze" in reflector, it'll tell you where it's being called from and who is using it.

Comment: Sorry, thought of another product. ReSharper and Reflector use static and/or dynamic analysis and this is the way to go for reasons explained before.

Comment: Reflector, ILSpy, and others also don't do what you want, they're not going to analyse the "If today is Monday" part in your code. Do you want this information at  runtime, or as part of static analysis?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Reflector does IL analysis it is not same as what you ask. It never tell you what is loaded, It just checks for the references (same like VS Find all references menu)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: I understand the difference. I guess I was just reponding to comments and CodeCaster's and William vvan Rumpt's comments mixed up the two isues again. Just to clarify, I get it: if I want *types that could be potentially loaded*, I could use any static analysis tool. If, however, I wanted to find out in a given execution environment, at a given point in time, which objects are loaded, then a debugger should be able to tell me that. So, compile time analysis == static analysis. Run-time reflection/inspection == debugger info.

Answer (score 1):

So to be clear the question is how do you find out if a class is used somewhere within the current project, which is a project that you have the source code for?

Assuming you are using Visual Studio, the easiest thing to do would be to load that project (not the entire multi-project solution) and then right-click on the class name and select "Find All References" (Shift + F12). The results will show each spot within the project that the class is used. In your case if the results are > 1 then the class is used somewhere within the project.

In your example the Rat class would only have one entry in the search results. The Cat and Dog classes would have two results.

Comment: The question was how to find it out programmatically.